# How to declare file type associations in package.appxmanifest file to support all types of files in windows 8 metro app?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, appxmanifest

I want to  declare file type associations in package.appxmanifest file to support all types of files. I tried with ".*", but this dint work.

I want to access KnownFolders.Documents Library from the app. So I have manually added the capability in my package.appxmanifest file. Now this requires me to specify all the file types which can be accessed. 
So I want to  declare the file type associations in package.appxmanifest file to support all types of files.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this: wildcards aren't supported, and you must add the file types the app supports explicitly.

Instead of tying the app to the documents library you can use a FolderPicker to let the user choose where to save or load its files the first time the app runs. You can cache this access in a FutureAccessList so the app can use it without asking the next time.

--Rob